# BFS Traversal over a graph question

Tags: graphs, breadth-first-search

[image]

Starting from a random node, which of these series **can** be a BFS traversal (L to R)?

1 MNOPQR
2 NQMPOR
3 QMNPRO
4 QMNPOR

Now, I understand that my answer (1- MNOPQR) is wrong because I got confused with DFS.. and the answer is 3. but why isn't 4 right as well? I mean, it defines BFS... no?   Thanks!

Comment: I guess they talk about typical BFS implementation, which uses a single queue. This way, when you process M, you insert R into the queue. **After that**, you process N and insert O into the queue. So you see, O is inserted into the queue later than R, which makes 3 a valid traversal, and 4 - not.

Comment: @Dmitry I know that BFS starts from a point and goes to its neighbors, then it moves to another point. For example, we start at Q -> M (return to Q) -> N (return to Q) -> P  (return to Q) then we visited all its neighbors, so, we pick another point. O. visit its neighbors but they are already been visited! so, we pick another point, same logic to R. and we get QMNPOR (4) ... I don't see what is wrong here